# Bad resize issue with ui-grid inside a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am having trouble fixing the resize of a ui-grid inside a modal window

http://plnkr.co/edit/gte3RmDem5dLAa33h7Kr?p=preview

I posted this question earlier but now I have the exact same issue as I am seeing correctly reproducing in the above plunkr

```
<div class="fcGridStyle" style="width:100%" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection>
```

The width:100% is required to actually show the issue. I tried playing with the CSS but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Here's a plunk that fixes your problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/fcGykG?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You can fix your problem by using the `ui-grid-auto-resize` directive. Said directive is available inside `ui.grid.autoResize` module, so remember to add that module to your application in order to use the directive.

I have update your plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fcGykG?p=preview) to show how it works.